# Alignment of 2 columns of text

Tags: html, css

I'd like the text of my second column to start at the same level as the first paragraph of the first column (Lorem Ipsum text). Is it possible? Currently it starts at the same level as my H2 text which doesn't look good. Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/znD9f/

[image]

```
<div class="article twocolumns">
    <h2>Biography</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
    <p><strong>LOREM IPSUM</strong></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.twocolumns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
       -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
            column-count: 2;
}
.article {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 60px 82px 49px 82px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 15;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background: #fff;/* max-width: 23.5%; */
}
.article h1, .article h2 {
    margin-top: -4px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you need to use the `.twocolumns` class to div that doesn't have your heading i.e. h2 element like this

```
<div class="article">
    <h2>Biography</h2>
    <div class="twocolumns">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,....
```

and reset the default `margin` and `padding` for `p` element to make it more clear.

```
p
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

So basically apply `.twocolumns` class to those element which you want to break into two columns. In your case you doesn't want to have heading in that. So exclude it from there and put it outside.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/znD9f/5/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet supported in Firefox, but the following should work in Chrome, Safari, Opera 11.1+, and IE10:

```
.article h1, .article h2 {
    -webkit-column-span: all;
    column-span: all;
}
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/column-span.

And here's further information: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-css3-multiple-column-layout-module/.

Until this has broader browser support, just move the heading outside the `.twocolumns` div.

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work for me in Chrome. Can you create a jsFiddle that shows this working?

Comment: It works perfectly in IE10.  Not sure why it's not working in Chrome.  Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3beVW/1/

Comment: @j08691, seems to be the float that causes problems in Chrome.

Comment: Why the downvote? This answers the question as framed by the OP, which somewhat suggested that he wanted a css3 solution using column layout if possible without changing his markup. I've acknowledged the limitations of the answer (lack of browser support) while providing a link to documentation that backs up my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about just moving your H2 tag outside of that div?
http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/znD9f/4/

Massage the CSS a bit to get it the way you want.

```
<h2 class="article">Biography</h2>
<div class="article twocolumns">
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, take a look at this changed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/znD9f/2/

Tweak the HTML a little by moving the h2 out and wrapping the paragraphs in two columns.

```
<div class="article">
  <h2>Biography</h2>
  <div class="twocolumns">
    <p> ... <p>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And tweak the CSS a little to align both columns:

```
.article p {
    margin-top: 3px;   
}
```

I hope that solves your problem. It works on your example at least.