# Wrapping text with columns in div

Tags: css, word-wrap

How can I wrap the text inside one div with 3 columns? 
I tried this but its not working.

```
<pre>
  #about-text{float:left;word-wrap:break-word;width:100px;height:150px;}
</pre>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVKx1.png)

Comment: What does your markup look like, and are you willing to add additional elements? I'm not sure what you expected that code to _actually_ do, but check out [CSS Columns](http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns) and it's [browser support](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn).

Comment: look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326418/alignment-of-2-columns-of-text/16326586#16326586

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#about-text{
   width:700px;
   height:200px;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
      -moz-column-count: 3;
           column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
     -moz-column-gap: 10px;
          column-gap: 10px; 
}
```

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwY5u/

Read more about [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/columns)

Answer (score 0):

```
   style="word-break: break-all;"
```

Use word-break to break text over